# Microsoft Education - Class APIs - Get Just Students

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-edu

We are working the Microsoft Education APIs within Microsoft Teams and we require to pull the students for a class.

It seems that Microsoft provides an [endpoint to return the Members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/educationclass-list-members?view=graph-rest-1.0) from a Class which returns both Students and Teachers, as well as an endpoint for [just teachers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/educationclass-list-teachers?view=graph-rest-1.0), but there doesn't seem to be an endpoint for just Students.

We are getting around this by calling these two endpoints and then removing the Teachers from the Members list, but does anyone have a better solution to this?

It feels like a common requirement for the API, but something that has been missed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You solution with two calls and a logical subtraction is the correct one.  Thanks for the feedback, but we don't have a plan to produce a GET students API at the present time.